# LibGDX update: Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'

Tags: gradle, libgdx

I recently tried to update LibGDX to a new version by putting the details specified here;
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/versions.html

Into my build.gradle file which is now;

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = 'MeshExplorerV2'
        gdxVersion = '1.5.3'
        roboVMVersion = '1.0.0-beta-03'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.google.guava:guava:18.0"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    }
}

project(":html") {
    apply plugin: "gwt"
    apply plugin: "war"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.google.guava:guava:18.0"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"

        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')



    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

This results in a "Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'"

Looking at other people with this problem it seems to normally by related to the wrong version of Gradle.
My graddle-wrapper.properties file shows;

distributionUrl=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-all.zip

And some results show I should be using latter.

However, the LibGDX website seems to quite clearly be stating to use 1.0.0.
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/versions.html
So do any other LibGDX users have an explanation? Does my .gradle file look correct?
Or am I miss-interpreting what that;

```
* Android Gradle Tool Version: 1.0.0
```

Means?

The full stacktrace of the error is;

```html
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'MeshExplorerV2'.
 at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
 at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:177)
 at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
 at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:25)
 at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
 at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:507)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:82)
 at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:28)
 at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
 at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
 at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
 at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.configure(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
 at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:79)
 at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:30)
 at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:108)
 at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:42)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
 at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:60)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:45)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator.runCommand(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:186)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:49)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:36)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:51)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.handleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:155)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.receiveAndHandleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:128)
 at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.run(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:116)
 at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginInstantiationException: Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.
 at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry.loadPlugin(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:69)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.providePlugin(DefaultPluginContainer.java:103)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.addPluginInternal(DefaultPluginContainer.java:68)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.apply(DefaultPluginContainer.java:34)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyPlugin(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:101)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:32)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:72)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:114)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:39)
 at build_7jjmfqv6k3j7sdf85orgevst8h$_run_closure3.doCall(C:\TomsProjects\MeshExplorerV2\build.gradle:52)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:58)
 at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
 at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:91)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.project(AbstractProject.java:903)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:225)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:129)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
 at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.methodMissing(BasicScript.java:79)
 at build_7jjmfqv6k3j7sdf85orgevst8h.run(C:\TomsProjects\MeshExplorerV2\build.gradle:51)
 at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
 ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/ShortTypeHandling
 at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.getLocalVersion(BasePlugin.groovy:3612)
 at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.<init>(BasePlugin.groovy:258)
 at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.<init>(AppPlugin.groovy:34)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.newInstance(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:62)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry.loadPlugin(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:67)
 ... 73 more


BUILD FAILED
```

Thanks,
Thomas Wrobel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to ask you by adding a comment to your question but i don't have enough reputation to do so. Can you check the version of your Gradle and Gradle wrapper?

> [The version of Gradle to use for your project should also be updated to 2.2.1 or later.](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0)

Update:

My gradle-wrapper.properties shows:

> distributionUrl=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip

I'm using Android Studio with the  "Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)" option selected. Maybe you can try to do the same by selecting it in the project settings. Or [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27122704/3177465).

Comment: I must admit I am not sure how to check;
gradle-wrapper.properties shows;
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-all.zip

Also, should I be on 2.2.1 even though LibGDXs site says 1.0.0 :?
It seems quite a miss-match going on here.

Comment: Yes, changing it to 2.2 worked, but this is highly confusing at the LibGDX site specifies 1.0.0