# how to add test dependency with android gradle plugin experimental 0.1.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I followed [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) guide to build an ndk hybrid project on [Android Studio 1.3.0 RC1](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/1-3-rc-1) with **gradle-experimental:0.1.0**.

Everything is OK, but if I try to add test library dependency, I found the method `androidTestCompile` is not supported any more. Like this:

[image: Error: DSL method not found]

And `testCompile` also cause the same error.

The offical guide doesn't talk about this. So, how can I add add test dependency gradle-experimental Or this version do not supports this function?

This is my build.gradle(project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

This is build.gradle(moudle):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 22
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.0 rc3"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "co.yishun.onemoment.app"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22
            versionCode = 5
            versionName = "2.0 canary"
            testInstrumentationRunner = "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.pro')
        }
    }

    android.productFlavors {
        create("flavor1") {
            applicationId = 'com.app'
        }
    }

    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "c_test"
    }
}

dependencies {


    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
    // Set this dependency to use JUnit 4 rules
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
    // Set this dependency to build and run Espresso tests
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'


    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that you are using Gradle 2.5. Under `File > Project Structure`, navigate to `Project` and set the "Gradle version" to 2.5. Under `File > Settings`, navigate to `Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle` and make sure that "Use default Gradle wrapper (recommended)" is checked. Also edit the Gradle wrapper by editing your project's `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file. Mine looks like this:

```
#Mon Jul 13 17:55:42 EDT 2015
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.5-all.zip
```

I did these steps in the above order, but after thinking about it when writing this, perhaps it would be best to reverse the order. I found that I needed to completely exit Android Studio and restart it before all the changes were recognized. Perhaps something was cached somewhere, or perhaps this was an artifact of the order in which I did things.

Also, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811997/android-studio-use-default-gradle-wrapper-vs-use-customizable-gradle-wrappe) for a little more info about setting the Gradle version.