# Gradle sync failed: Could not create parent directory for lock file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.4

I checked out a git repository in android studio, but I'm in trouble with **`Gradle sync failed`** error.

When project wants to build, the android studio raise an error like as following:

> ```
> Gradle sync failed: Could not create parent directory for lock file 
> C:\Users\username\.gradle\wrapper\dists \gradle-4.10.1- 
> all\455itskqi2qtf0v2sja68alqd\gradle-4.10.1-all.zip.lck
> ```

- I saw some answers to the other almost same problems, but none of
  them help.
- Also I deleted cashes in .gradle directory according above path, but it does not work.

---

How can I solve this problem?

I appreciate you to solve this problem, thanks.

Comment: delete C:\Users\Mohammad\.gradle\caches

Comment: clean and rebuilt

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez I do that and then rebuild the project but it does not work, also I try `File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart` but yet not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this answer:

1. In the upper-right corner of android studio click on the `Gradle` tool,
   then right click on the `your project name` then click on the `Refresh Gradle project` as following:

[image: Gradle --> Your project name --> Refresh Gradle project]

2. Then click on the `Build -> Rebuild Project` as following:

[image: Build --> Rebuild Project]

Comment: This solution does not apply to the issue you have mentioned. You mentioned permission issues that would be solved by running Android Studio in Administrator mode. Refreshing and Rebuilding throw the same "Could not create parent directory for lock file" error. I just had the same issue and fixed it by running Android Studio in admin mode.

Answer (score 4):

Remove C:\Users\yourname.gradle

then close android studio
and Start Android Studio with administrative permission.

it fixed in my case.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who still encountering this issue, I have just ran the Android Studio as administrator and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the `Gradle user home` field was changed to a non-default folder. However, that folder is NOT existed anymore (due to disk partition or something similar). Then, just remove the non-default folder to make Android Studio download Gradle stuff again to default folder - `C:\Users\user-name\.gradle` (or you can specify any other new valid folder I think).
[image: `Gradle user home config]

Answer (score 1):

Same issue had troubled me long enough before I found this [link for same issue in Intellij.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-252756/Could-not-create-parent-directory-error-when-compiling-gradle-project) After going the conversation, I found this is a **permissions** **issue** - which I should have figured out as the error clearly says "Failed to **create** parent **directory**".

I simply gave required permissions to the gradle directory and it worked.
Similar to below(replace `path_to_gradle` to your actual path) :

> chmod ugo+rwx <path_to_gradle>

Answer (score 0):

Run this following command:

```
gradlew clean
gradlew assembleDebug
```

If this does not work use following command.

```
gradlew --update-locks assembleDebug
```

Answer (score -1):

Delete '.gradle' file from the location C:\Users\your_computer_name.gradle
After deletion the .gradle file close the Android studio.
And open the Android studio
Problem is fix