# Design editor is unavailable

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Gradle sync failed: Could not create parent directory for lock file C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle-6.3-all\gradle-6.3\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.6.4-all\ankdp27end7byghfw1q2sw75f\gradle-5.6.4-all.zip.lck
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (1 s 119 ms)

Comment: You are only putting your logcat please explain the question or the problem or post your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle sync failed: Could not create parent directory for lock file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56450134/gradle-sync-failed-could-not-create-parent-directory-for-lock-file)