# IntelliJ's default gradle wrapper version - where is it configured

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have Gradle version 2.12 installed on my Mac OS. But when I create a new Gradle project from scratch using IntelliJ, and then select 'Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)', I see the project will be set up with a Gradle Wrapper that is version 3.1 - as in the gradle-wrapper.properties file.

I'd like to understand how IntelliJ chooses version 3.1 as the default version? I can't seem to find where it is configured.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio: "Use default gradle wrapper" vs. "Use customizable gradle wrapper"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811997/android-studio-use-default-gradle-wrapper-vs-use-customizable-gradle-wrappe)

Comment: Hi, no, that doesn't solve my problem. On that page, the answer said 'using the default gradle wrapper means that Gradle controls the version number', and that the version is stored in gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties. But my question is why it is 3.1? Because that property file is actually generated by gradle when I create a new gradle project.

Comment: Many things could influence that in your environment, as you can see in the other question. Since other people cannot see how your computer is set up, it is impossible to tell for your case.